# Как реализовать удаление i-го элемента стека?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Данный код в списке удаляет идущие подряд три или более одинаковых элемента. Необходимо реализовать то же самое, но с использованием стека.
Мне осталось заменить stack.pop(i) функцией pop(), описанной в коде.
Спасибо за помощь!

(В стек можно помещать и извлекать только крайние элементы, то есть только первый и последний)

```py
def push(val):
    stack.append(val)

def pop():
    return stack.pop()

def size():
    return len(stack)

#stack = list(map(int, (input().split())))
stack = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6]
destroyed = 0
i=0

while i<=size()-3:
    if stack[i] == stack[i + 1] == stack[i + 2]:
        while ((i+1)<size()) and (stack[i] == stack[i + 1]):
            stack.pop(i + 1)
            destroyed += 1
        stack.pop(i)
        destroyed += 1
        i = -1
    i+=1

print(destroyed)
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? У вас же используется список как стек. Или не знаете как в вашу функцию передавать индекс, чтобы она могла его в `stack.pop` передать?

Comment: Да, как раз с этим пытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто повторить семантику `pop`. Она возвращает **последний элемент**, либо при указании индекса, элемент с тем индексом. Для возвращения последнего элемента можно использовать `-1` индекс.

Пример функции:

```
def pop(index=-1):
    return stack.pop(index)
```

Тогда `pop()` будет работать, а с ним и:

- `stack.pop(i + 1)` -> `pop(i + 1)`
- `stack.pop(i)` -> `pop(i)`

Код:

```
def push(val):
    stack.append(val)

def pop(index=-1):
    return stack.pop(index)

def size():
    return len(stack)

#stack = list(map(int, (input().split())))
stack = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6]
destroyed = 0
i = 0

while i <= size() - 3:
    if stack[i] == stack[i + 1] == stack[i + 2]:
        x = stack[i]
        while i < size() and stack[i] == x:
            pop(i)
            destroyed += 1
        i = -1
    i += 1

print(stack, destroyed)
# [5] 13
```

---

**UPD.**

Вариация через два стека: в первом уже есть данные, во втором мы складываем с конца первого стека и считаем сколько повторных чисел нашли:

```
def push(val):
    stack.append(val)

def get_last():
    return stack[-1]

def pop_first():
    return stack.pop(0)

def pop_last():
    return stack.pop()

def size():
    return len(stack)

#stack = list(map(int, (input().split())))
stack = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6]
destroyed = 0


last_x = pop_last()
counter = 1
new_stack = [last_x]
i = 0

while size():
    x = pop_last()
    new_stack.append(x)

    if last_x == x:
        counter += 1

    if last_x != x or not size():
        if counter >= 3:
            # Т.к. мы заранее кладем в new_stack, то в случаи разных значений
            # уже положенное значение нужно вытащить, а после вернуть
            if last_x != x:
                temp = new_stack.pop()

                for _ in range(counter):
                    new_stack.pop()
                    destroyed += 1

                new_stack.append(temp)

            else:
                for _ in range(counter):
                    new_stack.pop()
                    destroyed += 1

                continue

            # Сливаем все в основной стек и на следующей итерации начнем заново
            for x in new_stack:
                push(x)

            last_x = pop_last()
            counter = 1
            new_stack = [last_x]

            continue

        counter = 1

    last_x = x

print(destroyed, stack, new_stack)
# 13 [] [5]
```

Comment: Суть стека в том, что можно удалять только первый и последний элемент

Comment: `pop(0)` удаление первого элемента, `pop()` -- удаление последнего (тоже самое что `pop(-1)`). Нужно удалить 3 элемента, вызывайте `pop` 3 раза

Comment: Да, но у меня не получается реализовать удаление i-го элемента, с сохранением остальных.

Comment: @АлександрЛисов, переписал, вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Нет, ответ должен быть 13. Запустите исходный код. Должна остаться только цифра 5

Comment: @АлександрЛисов, понял

Comment: @АлександрЛисов, обновил ответ

Comment: Получается так, что i может принимать значения 0, -1 и 1, то есть кроме первого и последнего может удаляться еще и второй элемент.

Comment: @АлександрЛисов, запутался. Как вам нужно было сделать? :)

Comment: @АлександрЛисов,  обновил ответ. Чисто решение через стеки выглядит сложнее из-за необходимости брать элементы из основного стека и класть куда-то для хранения